# Using Semantic UI elements in a Bootstrap-based project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I'm building a website where a lot of the theming and styling is based on `Bootstrap 3`. But I want to use things like Multiple Select Dropdown Search boxes which are readily available in `Semantic UI` but not so in `Bootstrap`. I think it's a bit too late to shift the project entirely to `Semantic UI`. Also, I am aware that there are a considerable amount of naming conflicts between these frameworks. So using `Semantic UI` alongside `Bootstrap` doesn't seem like a good idea. So what can I do? My question is two-fold.

1. `Semantic UI` suggests installation using `Node JS`. Can `Semantic UI` be used in a project with a `PHP` back-end?
2. Can't I just use the source code for these elements from the `Semantic UI` `Github` repo and use it in my project without actually needing to install `Semantic UI`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The answer may be late]

I have experience on using the dropdown plugin of semantic ui in bootstrap project.

You can just include four component to make it work, they are:

- [dropdown.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/components/dropdown.min.js)
- [transition.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/components/transition.min.js)
- [dropdonw.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/components/dropdown.min.css)
- [transition.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/components/transition.min.css)

Besides, you will need to add some css to styling the label (because it is comflict with bootstrap) and make the delete icon appear.
Here is a working example I made in codepen: http://codepen.com/cambyliverson/pen/mRreXo

If you like semantic-ui, you can consider the semantic-ui skin of bootstrap: [SMTB](https://github.com/cblweb/semantic-ui-bootstrap)

Comment: Thanks a mill, this helped me greatly!

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. 

For those that arrive here now. 

Semantic-UI is dead (couldn't even get it with npm anymore), but has been forked to Fomantic-UI. 

You additionally need label.min.css and icon.min.css (with all the fonts). And it still works.

Comment: Also, if your project uses Bootstrap 5. This is important: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#no-conflict-only-if-you-use-jquery

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, I'd say don't do it.  They CSS involved in the 2 projects could easily conflict and lead to things like this...

https://slack-files.com/T0VNSF68H-F4NL9M950-ae64b77fc1

^  *GIF of a modal bouncing and flashing because of conflicting css*

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use **composer** to install semantic-ui as well. Relevant link: https://packagist.org/packages/semantic/ui
2. NodeJS is preferred because you can use it to build the files with the type of components you want. If you have NodeJS installed, you can use the **interactive installer** to just assemble and build the relevant files for you.
   http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#install-semantic-ui
3. You can also use a **CDN** for specific elements: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui
4. You can also use the github repo to simply pick the elements that you need, but it is always recommended to use a build tool so that you can compile all your multiple CSS files (or JS files) into one.

P.S. To avoid namespace conflicts for the elements you are using, for example, you can rename all the `modal` keywords with `semantic-modal` in your `semantic.js` and `semantic.css` You can do this with all other elements that have a naming conflict.